# How to zip all EXCEPT a few, specified directories?

Tags: zip

I want to use `zip` on most of the directories in my home directories but there are a few specific directories (let's call them `dir1` and `dir2`) with contents that I do not want `zip` to add to my subsequent archive file.  I tried

```
zip foo.zip ./* -x@exclude.lst
```

with `exclude.lst` containing:

```
./dir1/*
./dir2/*
```

but `zip` still is including the contents of those directories.  How can I have `zip` skip the contents of those specific directories?

Comment: I think this question would be better on SuperUser than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this using just:

```
dir1/*
```

in the file and found that dir2/ gets included but dir1/ and things under it don't.

Comment: I just tried a simple example as well and it worked the way I wanted it to (also the way you described), but when I try it on my actual (much larger) directories it still includes the directories I don't want it to.  I'll see if I can find a more accurate way to represent my actual larger directory structure, although I don't see why there would be a difference.